# Spring Boot 3 + Hibernate 6 migration: Timezone mapping issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm in the process of upgrading a Spring Boot 2 + Hibernate 5 application to Spring Boot 3 and Hibernate 6. While updating I noticed that Hibernate 6 handles the conversion between java Instant fields to a table column without timezone information differently than Hibernate 5 does.

In Hibernate 6, when persisting an object with an instance field having value `2023-02-20T04:08:00Z`, the value is mapped to `2023-02-20T05:08:00Z` upon retrieval. As explained [here](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-6-offsetdatetime-and-zoneddatetime/) this might be related to the new way of mapping Instant and Duration fields.

I managed to fix this by adding `@JdbcType(InstantAsTimestampJdbcType.class)` to every `Instant` field in every `@Entity` class in the application. However, I would rather have a single, centralized configuration for this matter instead of adding annotations to each Instant field in the application. I have tried several approaches:

Option 1: Adding the property `hibernate.timezone.default_storage` and tried out all the storage type options ([source](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-6-offsetdatetime-and-zoneddatetime/#5_different_TimezoneStorageTypes)):

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.timezone.default_storage=NORMALIZE_UTC
```

Option 2: Declaring a HibernatePropertiesCustomizer bean:

```java
    @Bean
    public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer hibernatePropertiesCustomizerPG() {

        return hibernateProperties -> {
            hibernateProperties.put(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.TYPE_CONTRIBUTORS,
                    (TypeContributorList) () -> List.of(
                            (TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) ->
                                    typeContributions.contributeJdbcType(InstantAsTimestampJdbcType.INSTANCE)));
        };
    }
```

Option 3: Creating a `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer`:

```java
@Configuration
public class HibernateTypeContributorConfiguration implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        hibernateProperties.put(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.TYPE_CONTRIBUTORS,
                (TypeContributorList) () -> List.of((jdbcType, serviceRegistry) -> jdbcType.contributeJdbcType(InstantAsTimestampJdbcType.INSTANCE))
        );
    }
}
```

Unfortunately none of the approaches have worked so far. Would anyone know how a `InstantAsTimestampJdbcType` can be registered? Or is there a better way to fix this?

*Note that modifying the table columns to add timezone information is not an option.*

Comment: How did you try to do option 1? As you didn't clarify that.

Comment: I used the property `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.timezone.default_storage` using the different storage options. I have updated my question with this info as well.

Comment: `hibernate.timezone.default_storage` should have no effect on any of this, since `Instant`s don't have time zones. Only `OffsetDateTime`s and `ZonedDateTime`s are affected by that setting.

Comment: Can you share the entity model and schema, JVM and Hibernate configuration, as well as the timezone you configured on PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Hibernate 6 maps `Instant` to the SQL type code `SqlTypes.TIMESTAMP_UTC`. This type code (by default) maps to `InstantAsTimestampWithTimeZoneJdbcType` or `InstantAsTimestampJdbcType` depending on the capabilities of the `Dialect`'s `TimeZoneSupport`. Both of these `JdbcType`s will convert the `Instant` to a timestamp expressed in UTC before sending it to the database.

If you set `hibernate.type.preferred_instant_jdbc_type=TIMESTAMP`, then this should force Hibernate to use `TimestampJdbcType`, which will *not* normalize to UTC, and will simply convert the `Instant` to a local timestamp and send that to the database.

Can you try that, and let me know if that has the effect you're looking for?

**PS** Note that using `@JdbcTypeCode(TIMESTAMP)` or `@JdbcType(TimestampJdbcType.class)` should have the same effect as the configuration property.

Comment: I have added the property to the application.properties files as `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type.preferred_instant_jdbc_type=TIMESTAMP` and it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Weirdly enough, I was facing the same troubles in my project at work but that didn't work for me. I ended up setting  the `hibernate.timezone.default_storage` property to `NORMALIZE` as described in Hibernate 6 migration guide:  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/migration-guide/migration-guide.html#ddl-timezones

Anyway, this post pointed me in the right direction, thanks!