# Hibernate: Unable to extract JDBC value for position `2`

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring/Hibernate to just read up a very simple entity using a .findAll() on a Spring repository, however get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to extract JDBC value for position `2`
```

In the debugger I see that this particular column is a TIMESTAMP column in postgres and Hibernate is trying to extract the value from the resultset using the InstantAsTimestampWithTimeZoneJdbcType class. However, this class is getting a SQLFeatureNotSupportedException with message "Not supported yet.". This looks very strange, Hibernate is incompatible with itself? (Using Hibernate 6.1.6).

Comment: What DB driver do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

Add an annotation to all Timestamp entity field like:

```
@JdbcTypeCode(TIMESTAMP)
```

Solution 2

Add a property to application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type.preferred_instant_jdbc_type=TIMESTAMP
```

(based on the answer by @Gavin King: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75519276/spring-boot-3-hibernate-6-migration-timezone-mapping-issues))